# Dynamic Host can be passed except giving in .json file?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using [Swagger-ui version 2.1.4](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), i have hosted it locally and provided it my own Json file and API it opens the document fine and lists all the method in the json file, host is given in .json file. i want to change it, that it is given by the user every time when it calls the index page.

```
 "host" : "localhost:1234"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically set the host:

```
window.swaggerUi.api.setHost('localhost:1234')
```

If you leave the `host` field off, it'll use the same host that the UI is served from.